# pass the checked checkbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is the checkboxes in my HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="1" value="French Fries" >French Fries<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="2" value="Baked Potato">Baked Potato<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="3"  value="Cole Slaw">Cole Slaw<br />
<input type ="button" value = "Enter my side dish selections" onclick="checkbox(sides.value1,sides.value2)"/>
```

What i want is when the user clicks the button, it should take first two checked boxes and then display it as:

```
function checkbox(dish1,dish2) {
  document.getElementById("side_one").innerHTML = dish1;
  document.getElementById("side_two").innerHTML = dish1;
}
```

I am confused on how to do this, can you please help me here.

Comment: Even though you want to display only 2 options, do you want the user to select all 3 radio options also?

Comment: @Gautham, assuming the user selects two options only - then clicks the button. There are many options but i included only three to avoid the lengthy question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the first two checked inputs with `[...document.querySelectorAll( ":checked" )].slice( 0, 2 );`.

What it does is to create an Array from a NodeList made of all the elements that matches the [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo-class and slice it in an new Array of two items.

Then you just need to grab the `.value` of the found <input> elements:

```js
document.querySelector('[type="button"]').onclick = (evt) => {
  const checked = [...document.querySelectorAll( ":checked" )].slice( 0, 2 );
  checkbox( ...checked.map( (input) => input.value ) )
};

function checkbox(dish1 = "", dish2 = "") {
  document.getElementById("side_one").innerHTML = dish1;
  document.getElementById("side_two").innerHTML = dish2;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="1" value="French Fries" >French Fries<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="2" value="Baked Potato">Baked Potato<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sides" id="3"  value="Cole Slaw">Cole Slaw<br />
<input type ="button" value = "Enter my side dish selections"/>

<p id="side_one"></p>
<p id="side_two"></p>
```

If you want it to search only in the content of a specific element, you just need to make the CSS selector in `querySelectorAll` more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByName('entree')).filter(input => input.checked).map(input => input.value)
```

This makes an array out of node list of interest, filters out all unchecked elements and returns an array that will have zero or more values depending on what is checked. You can then .join() it or otherwise do as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

basically, radio is a NodeList, so you can do this

```js
const radioValue = (radio.length > 0) ? radio[0].value : "";
```